# "None" after output

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class info(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):

        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def tell(self):
        print "infotell"


class subinfo(info):
    def __init__(self, name,age, grade):
        info.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.grade = grade
    def tell(self):
        print "sub-infotell"


tom = subinfo("Jack", 13, 98)


print tom.tell()
```

the output is:

```
sub_infotell
None
```

I am just wondering where does "None" come from?  How do I avoid output "None"?

Comment: I tried to run your code. It does not give the `None`.

Comment: @aaveg: Then you did something wrong too. Are you sure you ran *all* the code in the question?

Comment: haha.. got it. I typed `tom.tell()`. You should remove the print from your `tom.tell()` call. tell() function returns `None`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `print` from the `print tom.tell()` line.

Your `tell()` method already does all the printing, so there is no need to print the return value of that method. And since you don't actually use `return` in the method, the default value `None` is returned:

```
>>> def ham():
...     foo = 'bar'
...     # no return used 
... 
>>> print ham()
None
>>> def spam():
...     return 'bar'
... 
>>> print spam()
bar
```

Note how printing the return value of `ham()` prints `None`.

The alternative would be that you removed the `print` statement from your method and used `return "sub-infotell"` instead.